# web service to retrieve data from solr

Tags: web-services, rest, solr

how to write a rest web service to query data from solr server in java. I have the a java code to query from solr

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = null;

        try
        {
            server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr/");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery(solrquery);
        query.set("rows",1000);
       // query.setQueryType("dismax");
      //  query.setFacet(true);
     //   query.addFacetField("lastname");
     //   query.addFacetField("locality4");
     //   query.setFacetMinCount(2);
      //  query.setIncludeScore(true);

        try
        {
            QueryResponse qr = server.query(query);

            SolrDocumentList sdl = qr.getResults();
```

I need to get the same functionality in a web service by taking id as the query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to query the id passed as an parameter to the webservice -

```
    String id = "100145";
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/solr/core_name"; // core name needed if using multicore support
    CommonsHttpSolrServer solrServer;
    try {
        solrServer = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url);
        ModifiableSolrParams qparams = new ModifiableSolrParams();
        qparams.add("q", "id:"+id);
        QueryResponse qres = solrServer.query(qparams);
        SolrDocumentList results = qres.getResults();
        SolrDocument doc = results.get(0);
        System.out.println(doc.getFieldValue("id"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i want to write a rest web service not a pre java application

Comment: This code goes in the webservice. You can find a plenty on articles for writing a simple webservice and exposing it.